# Rank 2 disconnected Dynkin diagram

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra

Which group is represented by Dynkin diagram with two points which are disconnected?

P.S.- I am new to this. Sorry if it is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

A Dynkin diagram with 2 disconnected nodes corresponds to the Lie algebra $so(4)\cong so(3)\oplus so(3)$.